# My External mic cannot be reconized anymore after I Installed Irium Webcam

Tags: 20.04, laptop, microphone, ubuntu-drivers, audio-jack

I tried to unstall to solve the problem but I didnt not work.
I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS**
I looked forward over the internet to reinstall the Audio Driver but I didnt found a clear answer.
I'm pretty new at Linux.

Btw, It used to work well before Irium Webcam application.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If your provided details are correct, your system is behind on security fixes & upgrades, as a fully-upgraded *focal* or 20.04 system has reported itself as 20.04.5 for some time now (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ *shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded before that date*).  I'd suggest applying all upgrades if you're actually using 20.04.4 as you state.

Comment: I will give a try! I didnt know it, thx a bunch